# Chrome extension issue in block-chain transaction

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, blockchain

Basically I want a chrome extension which takes data from block-chain and display in browser content-script also when user click on that data one transaction happen which will increase the count in block-chain.

I am able to retrieve data from block-chain please check the below code.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    const ads = await advertiserAbi.methods
                     .getSpecificAdvertiserDetail(
                     "any address").call();
    this.setState({ads});
}
```

But the problem is coming in performing transaction. Please check the below code.

```
async onSubmitForUpdate() {
    console.log("Hello");
    await userAbi.methods
      .setStatistics("any address")
      .send({
      from: "any address"
    });
}
```

Below is the error which I am getting.

```
POST https://rinkeby.infura.io/<--specific address--> 405 ()

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
at Object.InvalidResponse (content.js:108391)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (content.js:119211)
```

Comment: Google says "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed response status code indicates that the request method is known by the server but has been disabled and cannot be used."

Comment: Dear @wOxxOm any suggestions, on how to tackle that.